# log4j. How to catch log events from dependency library

Tags: java, log4j

I have a project where I use *my own* utility library (.jar file). How I can see logs from utility library in my main project? They both have configured `log4j.xml` files.

Comment: Do you know how the utility library configures its logging? You could modify its `log4j.xml`

Comment: @MiserableVariable yes, it's my own library, I have all source code and can modify it. But what I need to change? It's about `additivity` option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a library, *do not* include a logging configuration file in that library. Log4J will grab the first config file that it finds on the classpath, which means that your library's file might override the users settings. They will hate you for that.

The *only* place that you should package a logging configuration file is in the final application.

If you want logging in your tests, include a logging config on a test-only classpath (tools like Maven and Ant make this very easy for you).

Comment: Thanks, so I will caught all log messages from library on `root` logger? But other libraries will log to root logger too? So how I can catch logs only from my utility library and final application (not from all dependency libs)? I need to provide new `logger` section in `log4j.xml` with name of my utility lib?

Comment: @MyTitle - exactly. You would normally set your root logger to `WARN` or `ERROR`, and then add specific config for the logs that you want to pay more attention to (eg, I have `org.hibernate` set to `INFO`, and can increase it to `DEBUG` or `TRACE` as needed).